# How to delete all the data in two columns using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am developing a console application which returns data from two columns. However, I would like that when the string "delete" is given as input, **all the data in the two columns (username and password) are deleted.** I tried to search online but couldn't find what I wanted. Anyone know **how I could do**?

**I want to delete all the rows in my columns**

Comment: Probably you need to write code that transmits the command to delete the 'rows' to your database server. Did you write anything? Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't delete 'columns' but you delete 'rows' but to delete a specific row inside a collection of 'rows' (record) you need to know something that identifies uniquely the row between the other. This identifying value is used in the WHERE sql statement to allow the server to delete the right row.

So for example

```
using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("....."))
{
    cn.Open();
    query = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserName = @name";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
    command.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Steve";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Note how the sql text uses a parameter placeholder "@name" and then the Parameters collection of the MySqlCommand is filled with the value to delete and the WHERE command specifies the field used to find that particular value.

On the other hand, if you want to delete the WHOLE table and not a single row you can use a more direct command like

```
using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("....."))
{
    cn.Open();
    query = "TRUNCATE TABLE Users";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: sorry I expressed myself wrong in the question. I was trying to delete all the contents of the password and username columns

Comment: I solved it by assigning to the query: "DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserName != @name";

Comment: Not sure if I understood you. This will delete the rows of every user in that table except the one with the name provided.

Comment: I wanted that when someone wrote that command ("delete") it would delete all the rows inside the username and password

Comment: Let me try to explain it better. A user is a collection of informations like username, password, address maybe splitted in street,city,cap,province etc and each piece of this information is an attribute (call it field or column) of that user. A database table contains many rows of this kind one for each user you want to store. DELETING is the act of removing the WHOLE rows of a set of users (which one or ones depends on the WHERE statement). After a delete nothing remains in the table for that user. If you want to 'clear' just the information for a specific user that you use the UPDATE statmt

Comment: Updating a database field with new information (like clearing the previous data) is accomplished with the UPDATE statement, but in this case updating the username and password with a blank value doesn't make sense. You leave a row into the database table without crucial information about that user, unless you have other informations to identify the row. In that case instead of DELETE, you write "UPDATE users SET username = '', [password]='' WHERE Username = @name"

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

You can try the `UPDATE` query to remove all the data in a certain column:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter command: ");
string command = Console.ReadLine();

if(command == "delete")
{
    using(MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Your connection string"))
    {
        cn.Open();
        query = "UPDATE TableName SET [Username] = '', [Password] = ''";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is this error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[username][password] FROM users' at line 1'

Comment: @Steve How should i do?

Comment: @PietroContadini so I've update the query because the DELETE syntax won't work, so you can use the UPDATE syntax.

Comment: @Andrei But it keeps giving me a syntax error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[username] = '', [password] = ''' at line 1'